# Extracting data from python wsdl client using suds

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, suds

I have created the following Python code that reads a method from a webservice:

```
def GetWeatherParameters():
""""""
client = Client('www.address.asmx?wsdl')
#WebServiceClient.GetWeatherParameters()

return client.service.GetWeatherParameters()
```

It works fine and I get the data returned and can print it, however the data returned contains mutltiple columns and this code just prints out everything at once.

Does anybody know how I can extract the returned data column by column?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the returned data - a handy way to display it nicely is to use `pprint`:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(your_data)
```

That'll format it nicely so it's easier to see the structure. Then if it's a list or similar, to get the first row you can do your_data[0] to get the first one, or loop, to print it row by row:

```
for row in your_data:
    print row
    print row[0] # could be the first column...
```

And go from there...